# Align items before treeview in ul / li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this sample of code:

```
<ul>
    <li>group 1
    <ul>
    <li>group 1.1</li>
    <li> group 1.2</li>
    <li>group 1.3
    <ul> 
    <li>group 1.3.1</li>
    <li> group 1.3.2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li>group 2</li>
    <li>group 3</li> 
</ul>
```

I want to add some formatted numbers before this treeview all aligned vertically on the left so that the outouput would be something like:

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">10</span>group 1
    <ul>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">20</span>group 1.1</li>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">15</span> group 1.2</li>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">07</span>group 1.3
    <ul> 
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">100</span>group 1.3.1</li>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">08</span> group 1.3.2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">90</span>group 2</li>
    <li><span style="margin-left:-30px">110</span>group 3</li>
    
</ul>
```

I tried adding  on the left and align the numbers in those but
that does not work.

**Any suggestion ?**

Thanks

Comment: This is invalid HTML, you can only have `<li>` inside `<ul>` . You will have to use `<ul> <li> <ul> ... </ul> </li> </ul>` to have nested lists.

Comment: HTML is correct. Please try it in a brower and see the result.

Comment: @JDEC `ul`s cannot be **direct children** of other `ul`s. The browsers will fix your errors, doesn't mean its not an error, try the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and see for yourself.

Comment: @JDEC. The embedded `ul` structures should be within an `li` tag of the parent `ul` tag.

Comment: I edited and corrected the code. Thanks if you could reopen the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution using CSS. Let me know if this help you out.

```css
.top-level-list {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

li>span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <ul class="top-level-list">
          <li><span>1000.</span>group 1</li>
          <ul>
            <li><span>20.</span>group 1.1</li>
            <li><span>15.</span>group 1.2</li>
            <li><span>07.</span>group 1.2</li>
            <li><span>102220.</span>group 1.3</li>
            <ul> 
              <li><span>083113.</span>group 1.3.1</li>
              <li><span>17.</span>group 1.3.2</li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
          <li><span>90189.</span>group 2</li>
          <li><span>110.</span>group 3</li>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </hmtl>
```

Comment: This is on the right track. For the `position: absolute` to work, the root level `ul` needs to have css of `ul.Root{position: relative; left: 20px}`, where `Root` is the `class` attribute for the root `ul`, so that it becomes the positional reference point. The `left:` is set for the tree to leave enough room for the largest numbers.

Comment: To whomever marked this down, please provide a reason for doing so, otherwise we all do not learn how to provide better answers.

Comment: Note that `body>ul{position: relative, left: 20px}` will also work but would apply to all child `ul` tags of the `body`.

Comment: @Patanjali We can just use padding-left for Top level <ul>. It will work editing my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: The `.top-level-list` class also needs `position: relative` to provide a definitive reference point for all the `li span` tags. When things are incomplete, browsers may make a best guess render, which will work for simple structures. However, if the root `ul` tag was in another structure that did have a tag with the `position: relative` applied, all the `li span` tags would use it instead, which may really mess up the layout.

Comment: @Patanjali, Tanmay Verma: Just brilliant guys, you are the  best !!

You were so incredibely fast in providing an answer :) Thanks so much

Comment: Agree with @Patanjali, Thanks alot.
JDEC You'r welcome :)

Comment: If making this part of an industrial-strength solution, to ensure that any other descendant `span` tags added later do not also exit stage left, `li>span:first-child{position: absolute}`  would ensure that only the first `span` that is a direct child of the `li` tag is affected. The 'cascading' in 'css' is persistent in finding ALL situations where it can apply the rule!

Answer (score -4):

your code looking like your example output...
whats your problem? the look of the points?- this is done in css.

```
li {
liststyle: disc, circle,......;
}
```

sorry for missunderstanding in advance.

Comment: Quite clearly, the OP wanted a left-aligned column of numbers that matched the hierarchical list on a line-by-line basis. May suggest that if you do not understand the question, ask for clarification in a direct comment to the question, rather than in what people expect to be a solution.

Comment: My point was that you were not providing an answer, which is what is expected when you use the answer box. This helps people get quick answers as they don't have to read what may be irrelevant to them. A direct comment to the question clearly address the original poster (OP), without interrupting those who want answers. I am not trying to be anal here, but pointing out why this site uses this format, to help you be able to work with it better.